# Need help passing props to jsx (adobe jsx) file from js file in React

Tags: reactjs

I used create-cep-extension which is an npm built on create-react-app. It builds a bootstrapped extension/panel that works in any of the Adobe CC apps. I'm using mine in Adobe Premiere Pro (PPRO). I can't figure out how to pass props to a function in the index.jsx. This jsx file is Adobe's jsx which has nothing to do with a react jsx file and looks nothing like it. I think it's basically a very old version of javascript.

I can access the jsx file and run the code in it with this command:

```
loadExtendscript('./extendscript/index.jsx');
```

I can't pass any props this way though.

I can also execute general jsx commands to PPRO with this command:

```
evalExtendscript('alert(app.version)')
```

This is a typical command I would use in an actual jsx file but again I can't figure out how to access a function in the index.jsx and pass props to it.

Here is the code I would like to work:

```
main.js

let profileObj = {
    message: 'ExendScript connected'
};

if (inCEPEnvironment()) {
    evalExtendscript('parseObj(' + JSON.stringify(profileObj) + ')')
    .then(result => alert(result))
    .catch(error => alert(error))
}


index.jsx

function parseObj(obj){
    alert(obj.message);
    // alert('hello');
};
```

I've tried everything I could possibly think of over the last 2 weeks without success.

Here is a link to the documentation for create-cep-extension where they show examples for "evalExtendscript" and "loadExtendscript":
https://github.com/fusepilot/create-cep-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your jsx script path in the manifest, using the `<ScriptPath>` tag inside resources:

```
<DispatchInfoList>
        <Extension Id="com.your.extension.id">
            <DispatchInfo >
                <Resources>
                <ScriptPath>./extendscript/index.jsx</ScriptPath>
```

Then, you have acces to all inside your `index.jsx` and included files:

```
var myParam1 = 25;
var myParam2 = 52;
evalScript(`myFunction(${myParam1}, ${myParam2})`)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much Miguel!! I have been stressing over this for 2 weeks.

Comment: Follow up question. Can you have multiple <ScriptPath> tags? I'm trying to add another <ScriptPath>./extendscript/anotherScript.jsx</ScriptPath> but it doesn't recognize anything but the index.jsx.

Comment: You can do this inside the main jsx file, it serves as an entry point where you can write included or external script references, you may also pass them in from the front-end to run JSX code arbitrarily as well.